# Como eliminar varia filas de un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo un DataGridView con varios datos obtenidos de Base de Datos, lo que necesito es seleccionar 2 o más filas y eliminarlas tanto de mi BD y de la grilla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, eliminar las 2 primeras que seleccioné, ojo que no se sombrea toda la fila, a de ser por alguna propiedad que está deshabilitada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el el programa en el Foreach toma siempre los 2 primeros valores y no los últimos que estoy seleccionando, quisiera saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal y en q parte de mi código debo cambiar.

Psdt: El código es **dgv.Vinculados.Rows** por probar la imágen salió con SelectedRows

Gracias.

Comment: no tenes selectedRows (y menos Vinculados.Rows, que son todas las filas). Si no tenes a la grilla en modo seleccionar todo, vas a tener solo selected cells, y va a ser mas dificil saber que estas buscando

Comment: aqui hay un ejemplo que te puede servir http://blog.siinet.com/2015/11/22/asp-net-y-bootstrap-gridview/

Comment: Gracias, si cambio al modo seleccionar todo, tengo error al ingresar o editar un registro de la grilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo de que no se selecciona toda la fila es porque en el datagridview debes establecer la propiedad "SelectionMode" en "FullRowSelect".

Una vez que has establecido esa propiedad, SelectedRows va a tener información de todas las columnas de las filas seleccionadas, probablemente te falten columnas en la selección y de ahí el error.

Comment: Gracias, si es una propiedad que cambié, la propiedad "SelectionMode" está en "CellSelect", si lo cambio a "FullRowSelect" me da un error al editar un registro o al agregar una fila nueva y colocar datos en cada casilla.

Comment: Igual puedes cambiar la propiedad a "CellSelect" por código antes de entrar en el modo edición o antes de insertar una fila, y regresar a "FullrowSelect" después de.